# how to factorize two lists

Tags: perl, factorization

is there a way to factorize some lists easily in perl?

For example with 2 lists `('a', 'b', 'c')` and `('d', 'e', 'f')`
I want the output `('ad', 'ae', 'af' .... 'ce', 'cf')`

for now i'm doing

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @listA = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my @listB = ('d', 'e', 'f');
my @listC = ();

foreach my $elementA (@listA)
{
    foreach my $elementB (@listB)
    {
        push(@listC, $elementA.$elementB);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I would like to know if there is a more "perlish" way to do so?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for arbitrary number of lists:

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @arrays = (
   [qw( a b c )],
   [qw( d e f )],
   ...
);

my @result;
NestedLoops(\@arrays, sub { push @result, join("", @_); });
```

or

```
my @result;
my $iter = NestedLoops(\@arrays);
while (my @comb = $iter->()) {
   push @result, join("", @comb);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to make it more *Perlish*.

```
my @list_a = qw( a b c );
my @list_b = qw( d e f );
my @list_c = map {
    my $temporary = $_;
    map { $temporary . $_ } @list_b
} @list_a;
```

This results in the same `@list_c` you had above.

We need the `$temporary` variable because both `map`s will set the topic `$_`, and the inner `map` would override the outer topic, so we have to save it in another lexical.

Note that I renamed your variables and used `qw()`, since you asked for *Perlish*. The common consensus on style in Perl is to use snake case variable names. Despite camel case being named after our camel, we don't use it for variables. Only for package names.

Answer (score 4):

```
@listC = glob join '', map '{' . join(',', map quotemeta, @$_) . '}', \@listA, \@listB;
```

Comment: `@$_` should be `map quotemeta, @$_` to handle special characters, but otherwise nice. It even handles an arbitrary number of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative [CPAN](https://metacpan.org) modules are:

- [Set::Product](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Product)
- [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct)
- [Set::CartesianProduct::Lazy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CartesianProduct::Lazy)